# change stimulsoft report page size to equal text object field control width

Tags: c#, report, autosize, stimulsoft, page-size

I am trying to create a stimulsoft report for printing a single line of text up to maybe 50 characters on a continuous feed label printer, and I can't get the width or height of a report page to vary with the length of that single line of text.

Anyone have success doing something like I am trying to do?

I have tried a number of permutations of the Report/Page/Databand/TextField object's cangrow/autosize property possiblities, as well as trying to set the page width to the text field's width with C# script code in the various object events, no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can dynamically set the height of the page, depending on the amount of data on a page.

First set the page size to Custom, then write the following script in the EndRender event of report:

```
foreach (StiPage page in this.RenderedPages)
{
    double max = 0;
    foreach (StiComponent comp in page.GetComponents())
    {
        if (comp.Bottom > max) max = comp.Bottom;
    }
    page.PageHeight = max + page.Margins.Top + page.Margins.Bottom;
}
```

Report sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<StiSerializer version="1.02" type="Net" application="StiReport">
  <Dictionary Ref="1" type="Dictionary" isKey="true">
    <BusinessObjects isList="true" count="0" />
    <Databases isList="true" count="0" />
    <DataSources isList="true" count="2">
      <Products Ref="2" type="DataTableSource" isKey="true">
        <Alias>Products</Alias>
        <Columns isList="true" count="7">
          <value>ProductID,System.Int32</value>
          <value>ProductName,System.String</value>
          <value>SupplierID,System.Int32</value>
          <value>CategoryID,System.Int32</value>
          <value>QuantityPerUnit,System.String</value>
          <value>UnitPrice,System.Decimal</value>
          <value>UnitsInStock,System.Int16</value>
        </Columns>
        <Dictionary isRef="1" />
        <Name>Products</Name>
        <NameInSource>Demo.Products</NameInSource>
      </Products>
      <Categories Ref="3" type="DataTableSource" isKey="true">
        <Alias>Categories</Alias>
        <Columns isList="true" count="3">
          <value>CategoryID,System.Int32</value>
          <value>CategoryName,System.String</value>
          <value>Description,System.String</value>
        </Columns>
        <Dictionary isRef="1" />
        <Name>Categories</Name>
        <NameInSource>Demo.Categories</NameInSource>
      </Categories>
    </DataSources>
    <Relations isList="true" count="1">
      <Categories Ref="4" type="DataRelation" isKey="true">
        <Alias>Categories</Alias>
        <ChildColumns isList="true" count="1">
          <value>CategoryID</value>
        </ChildColumns>
        <ChildSource isRef="2" />
        <Dictionary isRef="1" />
        <Name>Categories</Name>
        <NameInSource>CategoriesProducts</NameInSource>
        <ParentColumns isList="true" count="1">
          <value>CategoryID</value>
        </ParentColumns>
        <ParentSource isRef="3" />
      </Categories>
    </Relations>
    <Report isRef="0" />
    <Variables isList="true" count="0" />
  </Dictionary>
  <EndRenderEvent>foreach (StiPage page in this.RenderedPages)
{
    double max = 0;
    foreach (StiComponent comp in page.GetComponents())
    {
        if (comp.Bottom &gt; max) max = comp.Bottom;
    }
    page.PageHeight = max + page.Margins.Top + page.Margins.Bottom;
}
</EndRenderEvent>
  <EngineVersion>EngineV2</EngineVersion>
  <GlobalizationStrings isList="true" count="0" />
  <MetaTags isList="true" count="0" />
  <Pages isList="true" count="1">
    <Page1 Ref="5" type="Page" isKey="true">
      <Border>None;Black;2;Solid;False;4;Black</Border>
      <Brush>Transparent</Brush>
      <Components isList="true" count="2">
        <DataCategories Ref="6" type="DataBand" isKey="true">
          <Brush>[157:218:78]</Brush>
          <BusinessObjectGuid isNull="true" />
          <ClientRectangle>0,0.4,19,0.8</ClientRectangle>
          <Components isList="true" count="3">
            <DataCategories_CategoryID Ref="7" type="Text" isKey="true">
              <Brush>Transparent</Brush>
              <CanGrow>True</CanGrow>
              <ClientRectangle>0,0,1.8,0.8</ClientRectangle>
              <Conditions isList="true" count="0" />
              <Font>Arial,8</Font>
              <HorAlignment>Center</HorAlignment>
              <Margins>0,0,0,0</Margins>
              <Name>DataCategories_CategoryID</Name>
              <Page isRef="5" />
              <Parent isRef="6" />
              <Text>{Categories.CategoryID}</Text>
              <TextBrush>Black</TextBrush>
              <TextOptions>HotkeyPrefix=None, LineLimit=False, RightToLeft=False, Trimming=None, WordWrap=True, Angle=0, FirstTabOffset=40, DistanceBetweenTabs=20,</TextOptions>
              <VertAlignment>Center</VertAlignment>
            </DataCategories_CategoryID>
            <DataCategories_CategoryName Ref="8" type="Text" isKey="true">
              <Brush>Transparent</Brush>
              <CanGrow>True</CanGrow>
              <ClientRectangle>1.8,0,5,0.8</ClientRectangle>
              <Conditions isList="true" count="0" />
              <Font>Arial,8</Font>
              <Margins>0,0,0,0</Margins>
              <Name>DataCategories_CategoryName</Name>
              <Page isRef="5" />
              <Parent isRef="6" />
              <Text>{Categories.CategoryName}</Text>
              <TextBrush>Black</TextBrush>
              <TextOptions>HotkeyPrefix=None, LineLimit=False, RightToLeft=False, Trimming=None, WordWrap=True, Angle=0, FirstTabOffset=40, DistanceBetweenTabs=20,</TextOptions>
              <VertAlignment>Center</VertAlignment>
            </DataCategories_CategoryName>
            <DataCategories_Description Ref="9" type="Text" isKey="true">
              <Brush>Transparent</Brush>
              <CanGrow>True</CanGrow>
              <ClientRectangle>6.8,0,12.2,0.8</ClientRectangle>
              <Conditions isList="true" count="0" />
              <Font>Arial,8</Font>
              <Margins>0,0,0,0</Margins>
              <Name>DataCategories_Description</Name>
              <Page isRef="5" />
              <Parent isRef="6" />
              <Text>{Categories.Description}</Text>
              <TextBrush>Black</TextBrush>
              <TextOptions>HotkeyPrefix=None, LineLimit=False, RightToLeft=False, Trimming=None, WordWrap=True, Angle=0, FirstTabOffset=40, DistanceBetweenTabs=20,</TextOptions>
              <VertAlignment>Center</VertAlignment>
            </DataCategories_Description>
          </Components>
          <Conditions isList="true" count="0" />
          <DataSourceName>Categories</DataSourceName>
          <Filters isList="true" count="0" />
          <Name>DataCategories</Name>
          <NewPageBefore>True</NewPageBefore>
          <Page isRef="5" />
          <Parent isRef="5" />
          <Sort isList="true" count="0" />
        </DataCategories>
        <DataProducts Ref="10" type="DataBand" isKey="true">
          <Brush>Transparent</Brush>
          <BusinessObjectGuid isNull="true" />
          <ClientRectangle>0,2,19,0.8</ClientRectangle>
          <Components isList="true" count="2">
            <DataProducts_ProductID Ref="11" type="Text" isKey="true">
              <Brush>Transparent</Brush>
              <CanGrow>True</CanGrow>
              <ClientRectangle>0,0,2.8,0.8</ClientRectangle>
              <Conditions isList="true" count="0" />
              <Font>Arial,8</Font>
              <HorAlignment>Center</HorAlignment>
              <Margins>0,0,0,0</Margins>
              <Name>DataProducts_ProductID</Name>
              <Page isRef="5" />
              <Parent isRef="10" />
              <Text>{Products.ProductID}</Text>
              <TextBrush>Black</TextBrush>
              <TextOptions>HotkeyPrefix=None, LineLimit=False, RightToLeft=False, Trimming=None, WordWrap=True, Angle=0, FirstTabOffset=40, DistanceBetweenTabs=20,</TextOptions>
              <VertAlignment>Center</VertAlignment>
            </DataProducts_ProductID>
            <DataProducts_ProductName Ref="12" type="Text" isKey="true">
              <Brush>Transparent</Brush>
              <CanGrow>True</CanGrow>
              <ClientRectangle>2.8,0,16.2,0.8</ClientRectangle>
              <Conditions isList="true" count="0" />
              <Font>Arial,8</Font>
              <Margins>0,0,0,0</Margins>
              <Name>DataProducts_ProductName</Name>
              <Page isRef="5" />
              <Parent isRef="10" />
              <Text>{Products.ProductName}</Text>
              <TextBrush>Black</TextBrush>
              <TextOptions>HotkeyPrefix=None, LineLimit=False, RightToLeft=False, Trimming=None, WordWrap=True, Angle=0, FirstTabOffset=40, DistanceBetweenTabs=20,</TextOptions>
              <VertAlignment>Center</VertAlignment>
            </DataProducts_ProductName>
          </Components>
          <Conditions isList="true" count="0" />
          <DataRelationName>CategoriesProducts</DataRelationName>
          <DataSourceName>Products</DataSourceName>
          <Filters isList="true" count="0" />
          <MasterComponent isRef="6" />
          <Name>DataProducts</Name>
          <Page isRef="5" />
          <Parent isRef="5" />
          <Sort isList="true" count="0" />
        </DataProducts>
      </Components>
      <Conditions isList="true" count="0" />
      <Guid>f54ce908f78c4855b4d9f0abc8f326b9</Guid>
      <Margins>1,1,1,1</Margins>
      <Name>Page1</Name>
      <PageHeight>29.7</PageHeight>
      <PageWidth>21</PageWidth>
      <Report isRef="0" />
      <Watermark Ref="13" type="Stimulsoft.Report.Components.StiWatermark" isKey="true">
        <Font>Arial,100</Font>
        <TextBrush>[50:0:0:0]</TextBrush>
      </Watermark>
    </Page1>
  </Pages>
  <PrinterSettings Ref="14" type="Stimulsoft.Report.Print.StiPrinterSettings" isKey="true" />
  <ReferencedAssemblies isList="true" count="8">
    <value>System.Dll</value>
    <value>System.Drawing.Dll</value>
    <value>System.Windows.Forms.Dll</value>
    <value>System.Data.Dll</value>
    <value>System.Xml.Dll</value>
    <value>Stimulsoft.Controls.Dll</value>
    <value>Stimulsoft.Base.Dll</value>
    <value>Stimulsoft.Report.Dll</value>
  </ReferencedAssemblies>
  <ReportAlias>Report</ReportAlias>
  <ReportChanged>10/17/2012 3:55:49 PM</ReportChanged>
  <ReportCreated>4/19/2011 9:33:49 AM</ReportCreated>
  <ReportDescription>Basic reports demonstration.</ReportDescription>
  <ReportFile>D:\DropboxFolder\Dropbox\Work\_Report samples\Dynamical page height 1.mrt</ReportFile>
  <ReportGuid>ee3572d318fe4031822ddce558c4622a</ReportGuid>
  <ReportName>Report</ReportName>
  <ReportUnit>Centimeters</ReportUnit>
  <ReportVersion>2012.3.1401</ReportVersion>
  <Script>using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data;
using Stimulsoft.Controls;
using Stimulsoft.Base.Drawing;
using Stimulsoft.Report;
using Stimulsoft.Report.Dialogs;
using Stimulsoft.Report.Components;

namespace Reports
{
    public class Report : Stimulsoft.Report.StiReport
    {
        public Report()        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        #region StiReport Designer generated code - do not modify
        #endregion StiReport Designer generated code - do not modify
    }
}
</Script>
  <ScriptLanguage>CSharp</ScriptLanguage>
  <Styles isList="true" count="0" />
</StiSerializer>
```

Comment: I think my problem was using a page object with a Width property that did not generate a render error when I assigned it text control object width values.  GetComponents() got me the object that worked, Thanks Ishma!

Answer (score 0):

I use from this solution:

Step 1 - set event for end rendering of report:

```
StiOptions.Engine.GlobalEvents.ReportEndRender += Report_EndRender;
```

Step 2 - set codes to handle height of page and other elements of report:

```
private void Report_EndRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (StiPage page in report.RenderedPages)
        {
            double max = 0;
            foreach (StiComponent comp in page.GetComponents())
            {
                if (comp.Bottom > max) max = comp.Bottom;
            }
            page.PageHeight = max + page.Margins.Top + page.Margins.Bottom;

            // set height for "Panel1"
            page.Components["Panel1"].Height = page.Height;
        }
    }
```

Thanks for [@Isham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1597249/ishma).